# Adding a dummy parameter to refresh a script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a dummy parameter to update a cell colour checking script, however whenever I add an extra parameter, I get an error in that cell. Range not found Line 7.

I think it might be something to do with the regexp but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```js
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

I got this code from: http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/2015/11/google-spreadsheet-count-of-colored.html